# Use list of integer type in a loop in python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
a=[]
b=[]

for s in range(10):   
    dw = s%5
    if dw == 1: 
        WD = random.randint(60,100) 
        DD =[int(round(dc*WD,0)) for dc in [.2,.2,.2,.2,.2]]
        for k in range(5):
            a.append(DD[k])
        print a    
    TCV = DD[dw]
    DDPT = [int(round(pt*TCV)) for pt in [.3,.5,.2]]
    for i in range(3):
        b.append(DDPT[i])
    for PT in range(3):
        for p in DDPT[PT]:
            print 't'
```

After running the code I get this error:

```
for p in DDPT[PT]:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
```

I was wondering if someone can help me in this regard.

Thanks!

Comment: DDPT[PT] is an int, what do you want to do with this int because you can't iterate on a int.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let's my DDPT=[5,2,3] and I want to iterate on it 5 times i.e., len(DDPT[0]) and then 2 times (len(DDPT[1]) and 3 times (len(DDPT[2]))

Comment: You don't want to iterate on it, maybe you want to create a loop ? Then consider using `for p in range(DDPT[PT])`.

Comment: Thank you! I already tried this but it didn't work. But I followed what maxko87 said. It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DDPT` is an array of integers, as evidenced in this line:

`DDPT = [int(round(pt*TCV)) for pt in [.3,.5,.2]]`

`DDPT[PT]` is some integer, and you are trying to iterate through that. Hence the error.

I would recommend giving your variables more descriptive names so these issues are easier to debug.

edit:

`for num_iters in DDPT:
    for iteration in range(num_iters):
        do_something()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let's my DDPT=[5,2,3] and I want to iterate on it 5 times i.e., len(DDPT[0]) and then 2 times (len(DDPT[1]) and 3 times (len(DDPT[2]))

Comment: You shouldn't use `iter` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `iter` function. It won't actually hurt anything here (unless the OP tries to use that function later in the same scope) but it's not good style to shadow built-in names.